# Cast an object that is not known until runtime to its type

Tags: java, object, casting

I have a tree that contains three classes of nodes. For example a root node has a left and right node of another node class. All the three classes implements an interface. The problem is before runtime I don't know which type left and right node has but I need to cast to the specific type otherwise I can't access variables of the nodes.

So how can I cast these node to its type at runtime?

```
//node has a attribut left of type of interface Visitable
public Visitable left;

....

//Visitable is the Interface that the three classes has implemented
(CLASS) leftNode = (CAST_TO_ITS_TYPE) node.left;

//I only can access isVisited, if leftNode is casted to its class
Boolean visited = leftNode.isVisited;
```

I tried "instanceof" but that doesnt work because leftNode might not have been initialized.

```
Visitable leftNode;
if (node.left instanceof NodeClassOne) {
    leftNode = (NodeClassOne) node.left;
} else if (node.left instanceof NodeClassTwo) {
    leftNode = (NodeClassTwo) node.left;
}

Boolean visited = leftNode.isVisited;
```

Comment: Why do you say `instanceof` does not work?

Comment: What is not working? Instanceof on a null will return false.

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. You said you _need_ to cast in order to access a field, but your cast becomes irrelevant, because the variable type will remain `Visitable`, thus it doesn't matter if you cast to `NodeClassOne` or `NodeClassTwo`.

Comment: @Zack WIth the second code IntelliJ tells me that leftNode might not have been initialized.

Comment: @Tom Without cast I get the error: Cannot resolve symbol "isVisited"

Comment: @Migster so set line 1 to Visitable leftNode = null. It is complaining because of the last line.

Comment: Well, I guess it is about time you create a [mcve], because like Zack said, you should actually get a "Variable leftNode might not have been initialized" error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do it correctly. `node.left` should be `not null` to correctly define it's type.

```
Visitable leftNode = null;

if (node.left != null) {
    if (node.left instanceof NodeClassOne)
        leftNode = (NodeClassOne) node.left;
    else if (node.left instanceof NodeClassTwo)
        leftNode = (NodeClassTwo) node.left;
}

Boolean visited = leftNode != null ? leftNode.isVisited : Boolean.FALSE;
```

Comment: Null check on line 3 is not necessary. Null instanceof SomeClass will return false.